# Rename igraph objects in a large igraph net

Tags: r, igraph, vertex

I have a `large igraph` containing info of 50 networks looking as this example:

```
Source                              Target
STAR-delta                          c-Lgt-1
SUN-2 receptor                      c-Jun
H2R reg class IA (p7)               STAR-delta
PtdIns(4,5)P2 intracellular         PtdIns(3,4,5)P3 intracellular
ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2                 ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2
```

On the other side, I have a dataset (`x`) containing the IDs and Symbols of my network.

```
Object.Name                         ID                Symbol
STAR-delta                         5580               PRKCD
SUN-2 receptor                     1439               CSF2RB
H2R reg class IA (p7)              5295               PIK3R1
PtdIns(4,5)P2 intracellular        No ID              PtdIns(4,5)P2 intracellular
ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2                No ID              ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2 
c-Lgt-1                            5894               RAF1
c-Jun                              3725               JUN
STAR-delta                         5580               PRKCD
PtdIns(3,4,5)P3 intracellular      No ID              PtdIns(3,4,5)P3 intracellular
ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2                No ID              ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2
```

So I would like to change the vertex names into Symbols (with IDs as attributes). I tried with

`V(g)[V(g)$name == "x$Object.Name"]$Symbol <- x$Symbol`

but it is not working. I would like to have an output like this:

```
Source                                Target
PRKCD                                 RAF1
CSF2RB                                JUN
PIK3R1                                PRKCD
PtdIns(4,5)P2 intracellular           PtdIns(3,4,5)P3 intracellular
ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2                   ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2
```

NOTE: dataset `x` and `g`  do not have the vertex name in the same order.

Comment: `V(g)$name <- x$Symbol`?

Comment: I am not sure if both objects have the same order. I get the following error: `Warning message:
In vattrs[[name]][index] <- value:
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to subset `x$Symbol` based on `V(g)$name` and `x$Object.Name`. To create vertex attributes, you can use `set_vertex_attr()`.
Try this

```
links <- read.table(text = "Source                              Target
                    STAR-delta                          c-Lgt-1
                    'SUN-2 receptor'                      c-Jun
                    'H2R reg class IA (p7)'               STAR-delta
                    'PtdIns(4,5)P2 intracellular'         'PtdIns(3,4,5)P3 intracellular'
                    'ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2'                 'ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2'",
                    header = TRUE)

x <- read.table(text = "Object.Name                         ID                Symbol
                'PtdIns(4,5)P2 intracellular'        'No ID'              'PtdIns(4,5)P2 intracellular'
                'SUN-2 receptor'                     1439               CSF2RB
                'H2R reg class IA (p7)'              5295               PIK3R1
                c-Jun                              3725               JUN
                'ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2'                'No ID'              'ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2' 
                c-Lgt-1                            5894               RAF1
                STAR-delta                         5580               PRKCD
                'PtdIns(3,4,5)P3 intracellular'      'No ID'              'PtdIns(3,4,5)P3 intracellular'
                'ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2'                'No ID'              'ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2'
                STAR-delta                         5580               PRKCD",
                header = TRUE)

## create network
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(links, directed = TRUE, vertices = unique(x$Object.Name))
V(g)$name # vertex names
E(g) # edge list

## change vertex names
library(dplyr)
x <- distinct(x) # get unique rows of x
unique(x$Symbol[V(g)$name %in% x$Object.Name]) # this will subset x$Symbol
# based on vertex names. This vector has then the same length with V(g)$name 
V(g)$name <- as.character(unique(x$Symbol[V(g)$name %in% x$Object.Name]))
V(g)$name # vertex names
E(g) # edge list. Expected output

## set vertex attributes
vertex_attr(g) # only name as vertex attribute
# x[match(V(g)$name, x$Symbol), ] not useful here. Can be used to reoder rows
g <- set_vertex_attr(g, "ID", index = V(g), as.vector(x$ID))
vertex_attr(g) # with name and ID as vertex attributes
```

Comment: Every `Object.Name`is unique. For some reason, the vector do not takes the same length with `V(g)$name`, instead all vertex are replaced by `x$Symbol`. It might be because I have some special cases where one `Source` has two or more `Object.Names`in `x`. I am trying to fix that. Thank you so much for your help! You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Here's your data

```
edge_igraph <- igraph::graph_from_literal(
  "STAR-delta" - "c-Lgt-1",
  "SUN-2 receptor" - "c-Jun",
  "H2R reg class IA (p7)" -  "STAR-delta",
  "PtdIns(4,5)P2 intracellular"- "PtdIns(3,4,5)P3 intracellular",
  "ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2" - "ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2")

x_df <- tibble::tribble(
                    ~Object.Name,      ~ID,                          ~Symbol,
                    "STAR-delta",   "5580",                          "PRKCD",
                "SUN-2 receptor",   "1439",                         "CSF2RB",
         "H2R reg class IA (p7)",   "5295",                         "PIK3R1",
   "PtdIns(4,5)P2 intracellular",  "No ID",    "PtdIns(4,5)P2 intracellular",
           "ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2",  "No ID",            "ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2",
                       "c-Lgt-1",   "5894",                           "RAF1",
                         "c-Jun",   "3725",                            "JUN",
                    "STAR-delta",   "5580",                          "PRKCD",
 "PtdIns(3,4,5)P3 intracellular",  "No ID",  "PtdIns(3,4,5)P3 intracellular",
           "ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2",  "No ID",            "ATP + PtdIns(4,5)P2"
            )
```

Here's a `tidyverse` solution with `tidygraph`

```
library(tidygraph)

mygraph <- as_tbl_graph(edge_igraph) %>% 
  graph_join(tbl_graph(nodes=distinct(x_df)), 
                 by=c("name"="Object.Name")) %>% 
  select(name=Symbol, ID)
```

You can further visualize it with `ggraph`

```
library(ggraph)

ggraph(mygraph, layout='mds')+
  geom_node_label(aes(label=name))+
  geom_edge_link(aes(start_cap = circle(8, 'mm'),
                     end_cap = circle(8, 'mm')),
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(3, 'mm')), 
                 width=1.5, colour="dodgerblue")+
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the nice example but since the networks are so large, my R session crashes every time.

Comment: Do you have challenges plotting the graph or joining nodes? Can you try and just `plot(mygraph)` which will just call standard `igraph` plotting function. Another thing you could try is remove `start_cap` and `end_cap` aestetics in `geom_edge_link`

Comment: With `plot(mygraph)` I get a picture of the network as hairball. When deleting `start_cap` and ´end_cap` I get the following error: `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

Comment: I edited the aestetics for `start_cap` and `end_cap`